# oauth-20090825.jar. returning null for authorization url

Tags: java, android, oauth

I keep getting `null?oauth_callback=x-opensocial-demo-app://callback` from a function `getAuthorizationUrl` in `oauth3leggedscheme`. When I traced to the library, `getAuth(providerName)` is returning `null`. However i've set my provider credentials on my main activity like:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    setScheme("x-opensocial-demo-app");

    Provider provider = new Provider();
    provider.setName("MyContainer");
    provider.setRestEndpoint("http://mycontainer.com/social/rest");
    provider.setRequestTokenUrl("http://mycontainer.com/oauth/request_token");
    provider.setAuthorizeUrl("http://mycontainer.com/oauth/authorize");
    provider.setAccessTokenUrl("http://mycontainer.com/oauth/access_token");        

    String consumer_key = "frttt-c3f1-cff4-qwee-e8deffc5d2de";
    String consumer_secret = "33b9e920d185c93a430a1d565e1c7621";        

    addProvider(provider, new String[] {consumer_key, consumer_secret});

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setupClient ();

}
```

what could be wrong here?